# angular empty object when looping items through this object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I paint the following html:

```
<table >
    ...
    <tr ng-repeat="item in countryItems">
        <td ng-repeat="monthName in admin.monthName">
            <input class="form-control text-right"
                   type="number" 
                   ng-model="countryItem[item._id][monthName.text]"
                   style="width:75px"
                   value="{{item[monthName.text]}}"
                   >
        </td>                             
    ...
</table>
```

displays values as expected, but dumping values like this:

```
<pre>{{countryItem | json}}</pre>
```

only shows

```
{}
```

also when posting this scope var "countryItem", the value is the same as the printed in the  element.

Strangely when I do mouseover over those inputs, prints just the input I passed the mouse over, so until I didn't pass the mouse over all the inputs the object doesn't get all the values ...

What is wrong? I expect to have the same value in the object which is printed in the table.

Comment: can you create any plunker?

Comment: can you post the countryItems structure and the data?

Answer (score 1):

`countryItem` doesn't exist, it should be `countryItems`

Like so:

```
{{countryItems | json}}
```

Or if inside your ng-repeat:

```
{{countryItems[item._id][monthName.text] | json}}
```

Also, you shouldn't bind a value to an input that already has an ng-model, since that's the responsibility of the ng-model directive.

Comment: Mike, you were right. Dumping this var was just for testing. Now I see it gets the expected value. The problem now, is the "countryItems"  gets the value of the elements just when I passed the mouse over. So seems to be reset once I passed the mouse. I think I'm looping wrongly here "countryItems[item._id][monthName.text]" creating another scope var or something else